# Adding object instance to the array in the next available location

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, event-handling, listiterator

I am working on my lab task.

**Create a class Book (String isbn, String title, intprice)
Provide parameterized constructor
Provide toStringmethod
Provide getter methods
Design the GUI on left
On press of the add button, a new book instance is created with the specified data and added to the array at the next available location.
Provide functionality for next and previous buttons to iterate through the array and show the corresponding record in the fields**

I'm facing problem in implementing add and next button using arraylist and list iterator. I have written code for that but its not working accordingly.

**Here is my code below
It contains two classes**

```
**BookGUI.java**
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ahmed.classtask.one;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmed Adnan
 */
public class BookGUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BookGUI b = new BookGUI();
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setSize(300, 200);
        b.setTitle("Book Frame");

    }

    private JFrame f;
    //private JPanel p;

    private JLabel l1;
    private JLabel l2;
    private JLabel l3;

    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JTextField t3;

    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton nextButton;
    private JButton previousButton;

    public BookGUI() {
        frame();

    }

    public final void frame() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        l1 = new JLabel("ISBN");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(l1, c);

        t1 = new JTextField(10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(t1, c);

        l2 = new JLabel("Title");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(l2, c);

        t2 = new JTextField(10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(t2, c);

        l3 = new JLabel("Price");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(l3, c);

        t3 = new JTextField(10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(t3, c);

        addButton = new JButton("Add");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(addButton, c);

        nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        add(nextButton, c);

        previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        add(previousButton, c);

        MyListener listener = new MyListener();

        addButton.addActionListener(listener);
        nextButton.addActionListener(listener);
        previousButton.addActionListener(listener);

    }

    private class MyListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String isbnTF, titleTF;
            int priceTF = 0;

            ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();
            ListIterator itr = book.listIterator();

            Book b = null;

            Object op = e.getSource();

            if (op.equals(addButton)) {
                isbnTF = t1.getText();
                titleTF = t2.getText();

                try {
                    priceTF = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! ");

                }

                b = new Book(isbnTF, titleTF, priceTF);

                book.add(b);
                t1.setText("");
                t2.setText("");
                t3.setText("");

                System.out.println(b);
            } else if (op.equals(nextButton)) {

        if (itr == null) {
            itr = book.listIterator();
        }
        System.out.print("reached here");
        if (itr.hasNext()) {

            b = (Book) itr.next();
            t1.setText(b.getIsbn());
            t2.setText(b.getTitle());
            t3.setText(b.getPrice()+" ");
        }

            }

        }


    }

}
```

**Book Class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ahmed.classtask.one;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmed Adnan
 */
public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private int price;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, int price) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isbn
     */
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" + "isbn=" + isbn + ", title=" + title + ", price=" +       price + '}';
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post only related code.

Comment: The problem is in action listener class ^^ in BookGUI class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `book` object inside the `actionPerformed(...)` which means that every time you press a button you start off with an new, empty `ArrayList<Book>`.

You should make the `book` object a class variable.

For example:

```
 private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();
    int displayedBook = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String isbnTF, titleTF;
        int priceTF = 0;
        Book b = null;
        Object op = e.getSource();
        if (op.equals(addButton)) {
            isbnTF = t1.getText();
            titleTF = t2.getText();
            try {
                priceTF = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! ");
            }
            b = new Book(isbnTF, titleTF, priceTF);
            book.add(b);
            t1.setText("");
            t2.setText("");
            t3.setText("");
            System.out.println(b);
        } else if (op.equals(nextButton)) {
           if(book.size()>0){
               if(displayedBook >= book.size()){
                  displayedBook = 0;
               }
               b = book.get(displayedBook);
               t1.setText(b.getIsbn());
               t2.setText(b.getTitle());
               t3.setText(b.getPrice()+" ");
               displayedBook++;
           }
        }
    }
}
}
```